Why did Robert see risk in the Air Force’s test plan for their B-29?
Frank and Robert are strategizing the positioning of observation posts, with a focus
on southern locations including a trigger point and a base camp. An extra post is
situated on a remote hill. Meanwhile, Robert notices workers constructing
a trench and learns from Frank that it’s for a line of lights requested by
the Air Force for their B-29, despite the trigger lines already being installed:

Groves: What B-29? Our bomb's on the tower.
FRANK: They want to use the test to confirm a safe operating distance.
Robert: That's risky.

Why did Robert see risk in the Air Force’s test plan for their B-29?
